# Powershell regex to replace quotes in capture group

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using this two line script to update a migration script - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12911#issuecomment-505596919.

```
$sql = get-content .\migration.sql -raw
[regex]::replace($sql, "BEGIN\s+(CREATE (?:VIEW|TRIGGER).+?)END", "BEGIN`nEXEC('`$1');`nEND", "ignorecase,singleline") > migration.sql
```

The issue is that it doesn't replace the single quotes, so if I have a query like this:

```
BEGIN
CREATE VIEW someview AS
select lastname + ', ' + firstname from sometable
END;
```

I end up with

```
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE VIEW someview AS select lastname + ', ' + firstname from sometable');
END;
```

And that doesn't work. Maybe it's because it's the end of the day and I'm feeling dense, but what do I need to do to also replace the quotes in what it captures? I know how I could do it in C#, but I'm a Powershell novice.

Comment: The regex does not match since there is `select lastname` instead of `CREATE VIEW` or `CREATE TRIGGER`. What is the rule you are trying to add to the regex?

Comment: I goofed up my copy/paste. Fixing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = get-content .\migration_old.sql -raw
[regex]::replace($sql, "BEGIN\s+(CREATE (?:VIEW|TRIGGER).+?)END", {param($match) "BEGIN`nEXEC('$($match.Groups[1].Value -replace "'", "''")');`nEND"}, "ignorecase,singleline") > migration_new.sql
```